# How to pass a scala class as an object into a function parameter?

Tags: scala, class, reference, arguments, parameter-passing

*How do I run the refint1 function? I've tried`var x = new RefInt(5)`* and then doing `scala> argpass.refint1(x)`but get a `found: RefInt, required : argpass.RefInt => Unit` error in the console.

```
object argpass{
       class RefInt (initial : Int) {
         private var n : Int = initial
         def get () : Int = n
         def set (m : Int) : Unit = { n = m}
        }
        def refint1 ( f: RefInt => Unit) : (Int, Int, Int) = {
          var x = new RefInt(5)
          val first = f(x)
          val firstget = x.get
          val sec = f(x)
          val secget = x.get
          val third = f(x)
          val thirdget = x.get
          (firstget, secget, thirdget)
    }
```

//How do i run the refint1 function?

Comment: First `f` is a **function** from `RefInt` to `Unit` _(equivalent of Java's `void`). Thus, you need to pass a function, not a value. - Second, since the function returns an `Unit`, storing its result _(in `first`, `second` & `third`)_ is meaningless. - Third, `x`, even if muted internally by `f`, is not reassigned, thus it may _(should IMHO)_ be a **val**. - Finally you can call `refint1` like this: `refint1 { ri => ri.set(i); i += 1 }` where `var i = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

As Luis said in the comments, f returns Unit, which is basically void. This should solve your problem:

```
class RefInt(initial: Int) {
  var n: Int = initial
  def get(): Int = n
  def set(m: Int): Unit = { n = m }
}

def refint1(f: RefInt => Unit): (Int, Int, Int) = {
  var x = new RefInt(5)  
  f(x)
  val firstget = x.get
  f(x)
  val secget = x.get
  f(x)
  val thirdget = x.get

  (firstget, secget, thirdget)
}
```

That being said, I think you can improve your design a little bit. Here's a different approach to solve the same problem:

```
case class RefInt(initial: Int)

def refInt1(initial: RefInt, f: RefInt => RefInt) : (Int, Int, Int) = {  
  val x0 = f(initial)
  val x1 = f(x0)
  val x2 = f(x1)

  (x0.initial, x1.initial, x2.initial)
}

println(refInt1(RefInt(5), ri => ri.copy(ri.initial * 2)))
```